# Unable to get the key of a value from an NSDictionary in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I was trying to get the key of a value by using the value itself from an NSDictionary in my Xcode project. I am using the following dictionary:

```
_itemDictionary = @{
        @"Electronics" : @[@"DVD player", @"Laptop", @"PC", @"PS4", @"Radio", @"Speaker", @"TV"],
        @"Clothing" : @[@"Air jordan", @"Bracelet", @"Fila", @"Jeans", @"T-shirt", @"Todds", @"Tag Heuer"],
        @"Cleaning products" : @[@"Ajax", @"Ariel", @"Bounty", @"Clorox", @"Dettol", @"Tide", @"Vileda"],
        @"Baby products" : @[@"Baby bottle", @"Baby milk", @"Johnson's wipes", @"Pampers"]
    };
```

And I am trying to get the key of a value that is on a cell of a table view like below:

```
NSString *name = self.itemNames[indexPath.row];
        
cell.textLabel.text = name;
//get all keys for current item
NSArray *keys = [_itemDictionary allKeysForObject:name];
        
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)keys.count);
```

So what I realized is that the count of the keys NSarray I am using is always 0 whatever the name of the item is.

I tried to see the suggested solutions before posting this question here, but none helped me and that's why I posted it. It would mean so much if anyone would help! Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you NSLog(@"%@",name); whats the output?

Comment: And you are actually asking for the keys of an object, that is an array which has no keys. Instead you can ask for allKeys and you will see whats up

Comment: @OlSen I tried to NSLog the name and I get the values of the NSDictionary that I showed. But I don't know why the size of the keys NSarray is 0

Comment: @OlSen I even tried replacing name in the allKeysForObject by a literal string for example: @"PS4" and it didn't work too.

Comment: The top level of itemDictionary only has arrays as objects, non of which matches a single item. you want to search the subarrays.

Comment: @johnelemans so you mean that I need to search the array of the one I found?

Comment: because arrays have indexes and not keys. In other words you may have expected to have multiple keys under one key.. {key:[key,key,key]} but thats not the case in your dict. you have NSDict{key1:NSArray[index1,index2,index2], key2:NSArray[index1,index2,index2]}. So you asked for an array which is accessible with key but contains indexes cause of its nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the hint given by John elemans, I realized that the dictionary actually contained arrays. And in order for me to check which arrays contained the name that I was looking for, I had to first get all the arrays in the dictionary and then go through each one of them and check which one contained the element. After that, I used the array that contained the element to get its corresponding key.

Happy coding!

Comment: in case that helps.. there are other datatypes that may fit your designpattern. like possibly NSMapTable. Welcome. glad you figured it out. :)